# Mapping of 6DOF Movement in Space to 2DOF (Kinematics + Dynamics)

Tags: rotational-dynamics, rotational-kinematics

I need to describe a 6DOF movement in space with 2 axes, Azimuth and Elevation (Inner and Outer Gimbal). The 6DOF movement is a platform disturbance to a stabilization system. The disturbance has 3-axis rotational and 3-axis translational properties, making it 6DOF in 3D space. I need to find/derive a mapping such that, for all said disturbances I can fully describe the dynamics and kinematics within my 2 axes of control.

I feel like I'm not asking the right questions when looking this up, so I appreciate all sorts of guidance on this; where to look, how to explain the problem to Google, etc.

To re-iterate, I need to find a 2-axis equivalent of a 6DOF movement so that, I could compensate for its effects by my 2 controllable axes.

Thank you kindly,

Comment: As stated, this is not possible. You fundamentally cannot describe a position + rotation with only two numbers. It would help immensely if you could sketch the situation, and perhaps a handful of examples of a 6dof position with the axis-angle "equivalent" you want.

Comment: I might have misstated the issue. Please see my comment on u/Mechanic's answer. Basically, when the gimbal is disturbed from its underactuated axis, I need to map this movement to the two axes I can control. I know it is possible to remain in the same orientation from trial and erro, but I do not know how to derive the analytics for it.

Comment: This kind of thing is very difficult to talk about in words, particularly if we don't know the right technical language. Please add a diagram of what you want, your other comments do not clarify things for me.

Answer (score 1):

It's just not possible. A 6 degree of freedom system will essentially be free to move in any direction and rotate along any axis. Two coordinates can in no way describe the dynamics of this system.

Comment: By physically rotating the axes with the disturbance given -basically roll the platform in a certain way- I can see that it is possible. Think about a 2 axis gimbal, you are rotating the platform directly from its 3rd axis, the axis it doesn't have, yet I can arrange the two axes in such a way that I remain in the same orientation. I may have misstated my problem as I lack experience in these matters. I need to figure out how much I need to turn the two axes to remain in the same orientation.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want to compensate arbitrary disturbance of a rigid body with some 2DOF gimbals.

This is just impossible. You can not even compensate arbitary disturbance of the body center with 2 axes because the gimbals have nothing to do with the 3rd direction perpendicular to the 2 axes.

Comment: Assuming it is possible that the gimbal can compensate for such disturbances, is it possible to project the 3 axis rotation to 2 axes? I am asking this because I have reason to believe the compensation part will not be a problem given that I can accomplish this mapping.

Comment: @GuarneerFPS Suppose that the center-movement is irrelevant, an arbitrary disturbance of a rigid body can be described by a rotation matrix. The rotation matrix is orthogonal and has 3 DOFs. The most the 2-axes gimbal can do is to compensate two of the DOFs and leaving one as free. So maybe you can express your demand as an equation of constraint and take a decomposition of the rotation matrix. The contents of rotation matrix decomposition on google may help you.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. In terms of the 2-axis gimbal compensating all disturbances, I cannot go into detail without disclosing know-how. So, I am saying let's assume it is possible and that part of the problem is solved. I am wondering how I can express a 3-axis rotation with 2 axes. Imagine I am rotating a set of axes around X, Y, and Z. I am now pointing at a new location. How do I point at the same location (new point) by only 2 rotations?

Comment: So we assume that there is a special axis for the system and you want to keep the direction of the axis all the time. The axis can be described by a unit vector, and any rotation can be represented by a matrix. Now given an arbitrary rotation matrix, then we need to work out a set of compensating operations to keep the axis fixed. This can be simply done if we set the special axis as z-axis, and set the compensating operations as rotations along X and Y axes: Just get the rotated direction of z-axis after disturbing, then rotate it back to z direction by two rotations along X and Y axes.